# How do I make set_printoptions(suppress=True) permanent?

Tags: numpy, customization, ipython

In numpy there is a function that makes arrays print prettier.

```
set_printoptions(suppress = True)
```

In other words, instead of this:

```
array([[  0.00000000e+00,  -3.55271368e-16,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.74443793e-16,   9.68149172e-17],
       [  5.08273978e-17,  -4.42527959e-16,   1.57859836e-17,
          1.35982590e-16,   5.59918137e-17],
       [  3.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,   9.00000000e+00,
          2.73835608e-16,   7.37061982e-17],
       [  2.00000000e+00,   4.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,
          4.50218574e-16,   2.87467529e-16],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,
          2.75582605e-16,   1.88929494e-16]])
```

You get this:

```
array([[ 0., -0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., -0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  6.,  9.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  4.,  6.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.]])
```

How do I make this setting permanent so it does this whenever I'm using IPython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this to the `main()` function in `~/.ipython/ipy_user_conf.py`:

```
from numpy import set_printoptions
set_printoptions(suppress = True)
```

and it seems to work.

In later IPython versions, run `ipython profile create`, then open `~\.ipython\profile_default\ipython_config.py` and edit the following line to add the command:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
        ...
        'import numpy as np',
        'np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)',
        ...
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add those to your `ipythonrc` file (located in `~/.ipython` on Unix).  You'd need the lines:

```
import_mod numpy
execute numpy.set_printoptions(suppress = True)
```

You can also add it to a custom profile or use another configuration method:

http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/stable/html/config/customization.html

Comment: I think ipythornc is deprecated, ipy_user_conf.py is preferred?

Comment: Dwf, add that as a separate answer?

Comment: I had heard that it was deprecated, but decided to suggest it anyways because:
1) The 0.10 docs for IPython (last stable) don't mention it being deprecated
2) It seemed slightly more straightforward than ipy_user_conf.py

Comment: Beware of http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/config/ipython.html
which, a level up, says "Starting with version 0.11, IPython has a completely new configuration system ..." arrrrgh

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to streamline it would be to create a wee module somewhere on your $PYTHONPATH, `printopts` say, containing:

```
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(suppress = True)
```

And then import that whenever you want to change the printing. You could also import numpy in your code as `from printopts import numpy`. That way you'd only need one import statement.

Cheers.

ADDENDUM: <strike>A solution for *interactive use only* is to set the $PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable to the path to the printopts.py file. The interpreter executes that file before anything else, when in interactive mode. Of course, then python will *always* load numpy, hurting start times.</strike>

Having considered a little more, what I would do is create a module, say `np.py` containing

```
from numpy import *
set_printoptions(supress=True)
```

Then always `import np` to get your modified version, for the reason in my comment below.

If you don't mind a hack, just add the set_printoptions() call to `the numpy/__init__.py` file, but you have to have write access to the numpy installation and remember to repeat the hack when you update python or numpy. I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: That's not any simpler than, in an ipython -pylab session, typing "set" and pressing the Up arrow to get the command I typed last time.  I want this to be in place *always*.

Comment: Well, if you always import numpy as with `from printopts import numpy` that will work. But ok - you made me google with that -1!!! See edit to answer.

Comment: Actually, I think this is simpler that doing the ipython thing and better than what I was saying in the `<strike>`-ed para above. Anyway, I think you should be careful about changing the default behaviour of a widely used package: other modules or scripts you use may assume the default behaviour and not give expected results. In your own code, that won't be released to others go ahead but remind yourself that you're doing something non-standard with the different import statement.